# Button do Modal não funciona!

Tags: javascript, html, css, front-end, modal

Eu possuo um modal que avisa sobre Políticas e Termos de uso. Basicamente ele fechará se clicado em qualquer área fora dele e no botão de fechar, porém tentei implementar (sem sucesso) que o mesmo fosse fechado quando o botão **li e concordo com os termos**. O botão simplesmente não funciona! Não faço ideia quando de qual seja o erro (de lógica, só pode), porque acredito que de sintaxe não seja.

**Segue a representação e o código:**

```css
.modal-container {
    font-family: tahoma;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    /*width: 500px;*/
    /*height: 574px;*/
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2000;
    display: none; /*pq nao ocultou?*/
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.modal-container.mostrar {
    display: flex;
}


.modal {
    background: white;
    width: 36%;
    min-width: 300px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 10px solid #2a8096;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px white;
    position: relative;
    
}

@keyframes {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0, -60px, 0);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

.mostrar .modal {
    animation: modal .3s;
}

.fechar {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    top: -30px;
    right: -30px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid white;
    background: #988b7a;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
h5 {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}

li {
    font-size: 1.08em;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

#li-destacado {
    color: #2a8096;
}

.btn-block {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #2e6da4;
}

.btn {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Políticas e termos de uso</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/politicas-termos.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <p class="logo">LOGO</p>
    <div id="modal-promocao" class="modal-container">
        <div class="modal">
            <button class="fechar">x</button>
            <h5 class="subtitulo" style="font-size: 22pt;">Regras para receber um livro</h5><hr>
            <ol>
                <li>Somente após se cadastrar no site você poderá receber um livro.</li><br/>
                <li>Só é possível solicitar um livro por vez.</li><br/>
                <li>Após escolher um livro, você deve indicar 2 novos leitores que ainda não estejam cadastrados na Livronautas.</li><br/>
                <li id="li-destacado">O Livro é <b>grátis. O custo do envio fica por sua conta</b>, para isso você precisará colaborar apenas com o valor cobrado pelos Correios, em média <b>R$ 10,00</b>. O prazo para postagem do livro é de 48h úteis após a confirmação do pagamento</li><br/>
                <li>Após receber o livro e terminar a leitura, você deve postar no site da Livronautas a sua avaliação e comentário sobre o livro que leu. Somente assim você estará liberado para fazer um novo pedido de doação</li>
            </ol>
                <button id="aceito" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Li e concordo com os termos</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        
        function iniciaModal(modalID){
            //nao usar essa primeira condição neste modal em específico.
            if(localStorage.fehaModal !== modalID){
                const modal = document.getElementById(modalID);
                if(modal){
                    modal.classList.add('mostrar');
                    modal.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                        if(e.target.id == modalID || e.target.className == 'fechar'){
                            modal.classList.remove('mostrar');
                            localStorage.fehaModal = modalID;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        const logo = document.querySelector('.logo');
        logo.addEventListener('click', () => iniciaModal('modal-promocao'));
        
        //Esse botão não funciona!?
        const btnAceito = document.querySelector('.btn');
        btnAceito.addEventListener('click', () => iniciaModal('modal-promocao'));
        
        document.addEventListener('scroll', () =>{
            if(window.pageXOffset > 800){
                iniciaModal('modal-promocao')
            }
        })
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você só está verificando o clique fora da área da modal e no botão de fechar.

Inclua outra condição no `if` verificando se o `id` do elemento clicado é igual a "aceito":

```
if(e.target.id == modalID || e.target.id == "aceito" || e.target.className == 'fechar'){
                          ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

### Dica

Não use `localStorage.fehaModal = modalID;`. Em vez disso use:

```
localStorage.setItem("fehaModal", modalID);
```

Comment: Interessante, dei uma avançada nos meus estudos e vi sobre key => value. Acabei encontrando problemas mais a frente nesse código, exatamente pela falta de atenção. Por Ex.: o nome seria fechaModal ao invés de "fehaModal".

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia.

Essa resposta esta sendo dada num contexto onde não se sabe se existem mais botões na tela, mas será considerada essa situação.

Uma possível forma de solução para seu problema seria especificar o clique do botão aceito, pois você sabe qual botão que é (existe um `id`) e sabe qual é a finalidade dele, fechar a modal e talvez executar mais alguma outra função.

Ao invés de ser executar a rotina `iniciaModal` (que por sinal, já estará iniciada) você poderia já estar executando o fechamento da modal e mais outra rotina que for necessária para seu caso.

A sua função está sim sendo executada porém a verificação do `if(e.target.id == modalID || e.target.className == 'fechar')` sempre está retornando `false`

Obs: Não sei se era realmente o objetivo, creio que não, mas cuidado com o uso do `addEventListener`, da forma que está sendo está sendo adicionada mais de `handle` para o `click` na modal.

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte :

```
document.getElementById("aceito").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("modal-promocao").style.display = "none";
});
```